# Why this object is null?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

I have a class with a static field like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static Guid MyField1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a method like this.

```
public void MyMethod()
{

   MyClass.MyField1  = Guid.NewID();

   Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>  { MyAnotherMethod(MyClass.MyField1);}) ;
}
```

Problem is that when I hit call to MyAnotherMethod(),I get an exception that 'MyClass.MyField1'  threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'. However if I replace the Task.Factory.StartNew call with below, it works fine.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyAnotherMethod, MyClass.MyField1);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: MyClass.MyField1 can't be `null` -- `int` a value type. Do you mean `0` (zero)?

Comment: It isn't. `int` can't be `NULL` (or `null` as it's in C#). How do you conclude that it is `null`?

Comment: Could you show body of the `MyAnotherMethod` method? Perhaps it reset a value?

Comment: I cannot repro.  Are you sure that it is MyClass.MyField that is null?  Can you post a small but complete program that repro's the error?

Comment: This works ok for me with .net 4.0.Please show the signature of MyAnotherMethod, @Hohhi - because he's starting a new task

Comment: sorry folks, MyField1  is actually a Guid and not an int

Comment: @Bond, I believe it is not multi-threading that is causing a problem so the tag seems irrelevant

Comment: "MyField1 is actually a Guid" - same difference, Guid is a Value-type too. Is it a `Guid?` perhaps?

Comment: Can you post the code of MyAnotherMethod?

Comment: Do you have any other code around these calls?

Comment: There are several reasons why your code could never produce the exception you've quoted. Please post the real code and the real exception.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a thread/caching issue.  In thread 1, you assign 11 to your property, but the value is in cache, which thread 2 does not know about (it is looking at the RAM for example).  To avoid this issue you can either use locks, or specify the [volatile keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) on your variable.

Try this:

```
private static volatile int myField1;

public static int MyField1 { get { return myField1; } set { myField1 = value; } }
```

Comment: Except that `Factory.StartNew()` should provide all the memory barriers needed. Always avoid `volatile`.

Comment: This didn't help. Still getting 'MyClass.MyField1'  threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: @palmsnow: Please post the actual code you're using, or a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. It's impossible to generate a NullReferenceException with a static field or auto-property!

Comment: @dtb: I have updated the questions. See if it helps to narrow down the issue. Otherwise I will try to simplify the issue and post more specific code. Its just part of big code.

Comment: @palmsnow: Your edit doesn't help. The code you've posted doesn't even compile (the method is called Guid.NewGuid, not Guid.NewID). Please post working code that we can use to debug the problem.

Comment: @dtb: Yeah I just typed the code here without actually compiling as seem like problem is my understanding between Task.Factory.StartNew vs ThreadPool. OK Let me cook up some code and will updated it here shortly. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the two versions of calling the method in parallel. In the Task version, you are defining the Task code as a lambda function with no arguments and inside you are executing the code

```
MyAnotherMethod(MyClass.MyField1);
```

In the ThreadPool version, you are defining the task passed to the ThreadPool as the code of method `MyAnotherMethod` to be started with the initial parameter `MyClass.MyField1`.

If after the call to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` you somehow modify `MyField1`, the task started will not be affected in anyway, because MyField1 was already copied on the stack and the task started executing.

If, on the other hand, you modify MyField1 after the call to `StartNew`, it is possible that a data race occurs before the method call inside the Task method occurs, and the method inside the Task executes with a different value of MyField1. I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say here...